# is it allowed to leave an attribute empty in the Entity–relationship model?

Tags: database, attributes, entity, entity-relationship, erd

Take a look at the ER diagram below:

[image]

Is it allowed to leave an attribute empty in the Entity–relationship model? Null values are not allowed.

So would it be possible for a person to have no pet according to the ER diagram?

Answer (score 0):

This diagram leaves the answer to your question unspecified: There is no authoritative specification for ERD that would prevent or - on contrary - allow attributes to be null. Nor are there standard types defined for ERD. For instance if `pet` is a string, would and empty string be null or not?

In practice, some modellers use SQL types and use the database conventions and the suffix `NOT NULL`.  Some others use the suffix `N` for fields that can be `NULL`. Finally, some use other textual (optional vs. mandatory) or graphical elements (e.g. bold vs non bold) to document attribute constraints.  All this leaves a lot of room for ambiguity.

If you want to be explicit on the minimum and maximum number of pets, a better alternative is to define an **entity** `Pet` and define a relationship between `Person` and `Pet`, documenting explicitly the **cardinality** (total participation vs partial participation and whether there can be at most one pet vs many pets):

[image]

Or you switch to UML: in UML the default multiplicity of an attribute is `[1]` (value should be present), but you are allowed to set it to `[0..1]` to say that there doesn't have to be a value.